# MySQL Return join of same table with same name

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am using mysql.

I have two tables

```
Students:
stud_num 
prof1
prof2

Prof
prof_id
first_name
last_name
```

Prof Id is a foreign key in the students table.

I want to get the stud_num and prof1 as first and last name and prof2 as first and last name

Here is my query that doesn't work:

```
select s.stud_num, CONCAT(p.first_name, " ", p.last_name) as PROF1, CONCAT(p.first_name, " ", p.last_name) as PROF2
from students s
inner join prof p
on s.prof1 = p.prof
and s.prof2 = p.prof
```

This does not work. Is there an easy way to do this???

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join TWICE to the professors table, but I would suggest LEFT join in case one of the professor's IDs is not provided

```
select 
      s.stud_num, 
      CONCAT(p1.first_name, " ", p1.last_name) as PROF1, 
      CONCAT(p2.first_name, " ", p2.last_name) as PROF2
   from 
      students s
         LEFT join prof p1
            on s.prof1 = p1.prof
         LEFT join prof p2
            on s.prof2 = p2.prof
```

Answer (score 3):

The Prof table needs to be joined twice, under two different names.
Try this:

```
select s.stud_num,
       CONCAT(p1.first_name, " ", p1.last_name) as PROF1,
       CONCAT(p2.first_name, " ", p2.last_name) as PROF2
from   students s,
       prof p1,
       prof p2
where  s.prof1 = p1.prof_id
and    s.prof2 = p2.prof_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
SELECT s.stud_num, 
       CONCAT(p1.first_name, " ", p1.last_name) as PROF1, 
       CONCAT(p2.first_name, " ", p2.last_name) as PROF2
FROM students s, prof p1, prof p2
WHERE s.prof1 = p1.prof
      AND s.prof2 = p2.prof
```

Comment: Thanks and fully agreed. I just thought after posting it and watching the other answer.